# How to create JPA CriteriaBuilder with many to many relationship

Tags: mysql, spring-boot, jpa, many-to-many, hibernate-criteria

Using Spring Boot JPA.
I have two tables with many2many relationship.
My tables are:

1. property_tbl
2. amenity_tbl (**columns**: name)
3. property_amenity_tbl (**columns**: property_id, amenity_name)

I want to get the items from **property_tbl** that contains **All** the items of amenity list.

I made a query( not sure if this is the best writing but it works),

```
SELECT * from property_tbl where id in (SELECT p.id FROM property_tbl p join property_amenity_tbl pa on p.id = pa.property_id where pa.amenity_name in ('amenity_1','amenity_2'...) group by p.id HAVING COUNT(pa.amenity_name) = 2);
```

I want to get the same query with criteria builder

```
@Override
public List<Property> findPropertyByParam(Params params) {
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Property> cq = cb.createQuery(Property.class);

    Root<Property> property = cq.from(Property.class);

    // add the query here
    // params.getAmenities()..

    List<Property> result = em.createQuery(cq).getResultList();
    return result;
}
```

How to should I write this criteria

Comment: did you try this https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tip-left-join-fetch-join-criteriaquery/